# LWJGL - Не отображаются текстуры, после рендера текста

Tags: java, lwjgl

Для рендера текстур и текста я использую библиотеку `slick-util`

Проблема в том, что после рендера текста, все текстуры показываются в виде чёрного квадрата.
Код рендера текста:

```
private static TrueTypeFont font = new TrueTypeFont(new Font("Arial", 0, 15), true);

public static void renderCenteredTextInRectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height, String title, Color color) {
    enableBlend();
    {
        font.drawString(x + (width / 2) - (font.getWidth(title) / 2), y + (height / 2) - (font.getHeight(title) / 2), title, color);
    }
    disableBlend();
}
```

Код рендера текстур:

```
public static void renderTexturedRectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height, Texture texture) {
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    {
        glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        glVertex2i(x, y);

        glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
        glVertex2i(x + width, y);

        glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
        glVertex2i(x + width, y + height);

        glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
        glVertex2i(x, y + height);
    }
    glEnd();
}
```

Остальные методы:

```
public static void enableBlend() {
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
}

public static void disableBlend() {
    glDisable(GL_BLEND);
}
```

Рендер кнопки:

```
public void draw() {
    int color = 213;
    if (isHovered()) color = 170;
    GLHelper.setColor(color, color, color, 0);
    GLHelper.renderRectangle(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    GLHelper.renderCenteredTextInRectangle(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height, this.title, Color.black);
}
```

Выглядит всё это вот так:
[image: Скриншот1]

Если же убрать рендер текста, то текстуры показываются нормально.

И да, цвет первой кнопки должен быть таким же что и второй, но, цвет кнопки меняется на цвет последнего(снизу справа) пикселя текстуры.
Ап.

Comment: неужели никто не знает в чём проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение данной проблемы было очень простым, жаль что никто так и не ответил. Нужно было просто перед рендером текстуры выполнить `Color.white.bind();`

```
public static void renderTexturedRectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height, Texture texture) {
    enableTexture();

    Color.white.bind();
    texture.bind();

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    {
        glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        glVertex2i(x, y);

        glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
        glVertex2i(x + width, y);

        glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
        glVertex2i(x + width, y + height);

        glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
        glVertex2i(x, y + height);
    }
    glEnd();
    disableTexture();
}
```